# MIPS - How do I store user input and store it in an array dynamically?

Tags: mips

Can anyone show me an example of how to first record the size, n, of the integer list from the user, and then store the n integers entered by the user into an array that can hold n integers?

I can't find something similar through google. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  What language are you working in?

Comment: Indeed, unless you absolutely have to do this in assembly language (which in this day and age, for a problem of this sort, would probably only be a "homework" requirement) your actual question should depend on the details of the user interface subsystem and the run time support environment, not on the processor.

Comment: What simulator are you using? `spim`? `MARS`?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach spim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at [this](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) list of MIPS system calls, the first 17 of which are supported by the `spim` simulator.

With that list in mind, here's the general approach you should take:

```
# read n from console
li $v0 5
syscall
move $t0 $v0

# allocate dynamic memory
sll $a0 $v0 2    # sll performs $a0 = $v0 x 2^2
li $v0 9    #9 is the system code for service(sbrk) whoes work is        
syscall     #to allocate dynamic memory

move $t1 $zero
move $t2 $v0

loop:
    bge $t1 $t0 end

    # read in and store int
    li $v0 5
    syscall
    sw $v0 0($t2)

    addi $t1 $t1 1
    addi $t2 $t2 4
    j loop

end:
```

Comment: is it more efficient to do sll $a0, $v0, 2 than to li $a0, 20?

Comment: They are not equivalent. `n` is stored in `$v0` but it needs to be multiplied by `4` to get the number of bytes required hence `sll $a0 $v0 2`

Comment: I forgot he was taking an input from user, my bad